# Converting a given 2d array into a binary image using opencv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, uint8t

**So here is the incomplete code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
arr= np.zeros((30,30))
# bw_image = <missing part>
cv2.imshow("BW Image",bw_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#please use arr at 4th line to complete the code
```

I am actually new to this and don't know how to convert a given 2d array into a binary image using opencv.
Please use the name "arr" for the missing part, as in my code, the array is not a zeros array, instead it has some random values of 0 and 255 of 400x400 shape.

Comment: Alright, thx for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [Numpy array of random integers](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 256, (400,400), dtype=np.uint8)
```

If your question is actually about thresholding, maybe you want:

```
_, bw_image = cv2.threshold(arr, 128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it worked! Btw, I am new to this field. Could you suggest me some resources to learning about opencv? Also, I wanted to know about '_' in the line: _, bw_image = cv2.threshold(arr, 128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

Comment: The underscore is used in Python (and in `bash` shell) as a placeholder for a variable we are not interested in and can't be bothered to think up a name for - it just means *"unused and unnamed thing"*.